# Prepositional phrase modifies another prepositional phrase? Or both modify the verb?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, modifiers, predicative-complement, attachment-ambiguity

Consider:

> Smoke hung in the air above the city.

I see lots of sentences containing the structure of "verbal phrase + prepositional phrase + prepositional phrase" like the example above.

I just do not know whether the second prepositional phrase (in this example, *above the city*) modifies the verb (*hung*), or if it modifies the noun (*the air*) in the first prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SHORT ANSWER: It modifies neither.

LONG ANSWER:
This is actually a more complicated matter than traditional grammar can handle.

1. Neither of these two preposition phrases<sup>†</sup> really modifies the verb *hung*. Verbs like this one are called ‘linking’ or ‘copular’ verbs because they link the subject to a complement which describes the subject—a *subject complement*.

   The most common copular verb is *BE*, but there are also verbs of perception such as *appear* , *seem*, *sound*, *look*, *taste* which ordinarily take adjectival complements describing how the subject is perceived, and verbs of location which ordinarily take  ‘adverbial’ complements describing where the subject  is to be found. In this case, intransitive *hang* takes *in the air above the city* as a subject complement.

   Note that transitive *hang* similarly takes an *object complement*: in the sentence “He hung the bag on a hook”, the preposition phrase ‘modifies’ the Direct Object *bag*, tells the location where the bag is to be found.

   For this reason I have to dissent from Nico’s characterization of this as a *dangling modifier*; it is both semantically **and syntactically** quite unambiguous what is where.
2. As for the sequence of two preposition phrases ... I’m talking off the top of my head now, and I think it likely that modern grammars have a more incisive description of what is going on here. But it seems to me that the second phrase does not so much ‘modify’ or qualify the first as it supplements it. This works rather like chained adjectives before a noun: in the phrase *a big red box*, *big* does not qualify *red*, it provides additional information.

   However, as Nico quite cogently tells you, it doesn’t really matter how you parse the sequence. You could flip this to *above the city in the air* and it would not change the sense. By and large, however, we prefer to order the phrases as you have it, moving from the more general location to the more particular.

---

<sup>†</sup> The reason for calling this a “preposition phrase” rather than a “preposition**al** phrase” is treated [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/11727/32).

Comment: Would the same reasoning apply to `smoke hung in a cloud above the city`? If `above the city` would modify `hung`, it would mean the smoke formed a cloud. If `above the city` would modify `in a cloud`, it could be interpreted as a pre-existing cloud holding the ascend of a smoke column.

Comment: @Nico To express your second version we wouldn't say the smoke hung in the cloud: we would say that it "rose into the cloud  above the city and hung there". But that's very far-fetched: how would spectators distinguish the cloud from the smoke hanging in it?

Comment: Thanks. Now, I see clearly that `hang` acting as a copular verb precludes interpreting this sentence as a case of dangling modifier.

Comment: @Nico Grammar has gotten a great deal more complicated (and a great deal more interesting) since I was a schoolboy 50+ years ago!

Comment: thx! @StoneyB You are really good at grasping the key point of questions. As an advanced English learner, I always run into all kinds of sentences the traditional grammar fails to explain. Nice job! I now understand e.g. "throw a ball up in the sky", up and in the sky can both act as the object complement here. They do not modify each other.

Comment: I'll respectfully disagree with StoneyB on one of his comments.  To me, "Smoke hung in a cloud above the city" clearly indicates "a pre-existing cloud holding the ascend of a smoke column". It's certainly a surreal image and I cannot imagine how it would be possible, yet the concept is unambiguous. In fact, it's a rather beautiful sentence.  Here we have two nebulous phenomena, interacting in an impossible yet unambiguous fashion, easily imaginable in the abstract but not as a concrete visual image, and all stated in an strikingly concise sentence. @Nico

Comment: Well, actually its not the "ascend of a smoke column". We don't know where that smoke came from or how it got stuck up there in that cloud, now do we? We don't even know what it looked like.  ***All we can really know for sure, is it was there.*** **: )** @nico

Comment: FYI, My wife, who is a writer, had a poetic interpretation: "The smoke = the cloud".  Kind of like "I am in my body" or "The water swirled in the sea". It can work if given the proper context.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Quite so. Indeed, I took "in a cloud" in Nico's first parsing of the version in his first comment here to be roughly equivalent to "as a cloud, in the form of a cloud".

Answer (score 1):

That is known as a [dangling modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier) and a source of ambiguity.

In the example `Smoke hung in the air above the city` the ambiguity is irrelevant, but in other cases the sentence would have to be edited.

Here's an example taken from the wikipedia entry linked above:

> I saw the trailer peeking through the window.

This sentence could be understood as either the person or the trailer `peeking through the window`. To remove the ambiguity, Wikipedia suggests to recast the sentence as:

> Peeking through the window, I saw the trailer

Comment: THX, but your answer helps me how?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng: sorry about the messy answer. I've already updated it with an example of the ambiguity discussed in the wikipedia entry.

Comment: so you mean "above the city" modifies "smoke" in my example? @Nico

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng: what I mean is that it is irrelevant. It doesn't matter whether `above the air` modifies `smoke hung` or `in the air`. In both cases the smoke will be hanging `above the city`. I think the example from wikipedia illustrates better this kind of ambiguity.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Nico is saying that **it's not clear** which it modifies, but also that **it doesn't matter** because the meaning is the same for both (in your example).

Comment: Maybe I am getting a hair-splitter here. I knew it doesn't matter which qualifies which for this example, but, as for some other examples, _which qualifies which_ would cause ambiguity. I just couldn't give any examples here, but I have seen some before.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence says there was smoke somewhere. And where? In the air and the sentence means the air above the city, and not the air above the forest or the lake.

Comment: I created the confusion by not realising that `hung` in `Smoke hung in the air above the city` is acting as a copular verb. In simple words, the sentence is equivalent to `Smoke was in the air above the city`. Without going into the details, I would say @StoneyB made the point that the wikipedia entry on dangling modifiers does not apply to copular verbs. I tried to come up with a good counter-example, but I failed.

Comment: Sorry @rogermue You fail to understand what I am asking here. thx all the same!

Comment: That's absolutely right. I fail to see what your problem with that simple sentence is.

Comment: I edited this answer to remove "lack of understanding" and "lack of imagination" text. Those non-answer elements could be posted as valid questions to enhance the author's understanding of English (complicated answers) and to meta.ell regarding needs of language learners (not knowing why questions are being asked). Also note that if you have specific questions *about* a particular question or answer, the appropriate place to ask for better understanding would be in the comments section.  A post in which 50% declares your non-understanding is not in the spirit of answering questions.